# Cannot get switch() to repeat itself after

Tags: c, loops

As the title says. I have tried EVERYTHING and i just cannot get it to work.
Anything that needs `<iostream>` as I don't have the competency to install it (my codeblocks is tell me its missing)

I've tried things with var,cin,cout,booleans and i cannot get this f******* to repeat itself. I've crawled through countless forums reading the instructions and I cant get anything to damn work.

Can you edit it such that if a user inputs anything that defaults then the user is presented again with the menu and the option to enter a number. It would really be appreciated. I just cannot do it myself

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main()  //main function
{
    printf("Airport Reservation System\n");
    printf("Menu\n1 - Flights\n2 - Passengers\n3 - "
        "Reservations\nAnything else to   quit\n\n");
    printf("Please enter menu number: ");

    int menu_number;
    scanf("%d", &menu_number);
    switch (menu_number) //creating the navigation menu
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Flights");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Passengers");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Reservations");
            break;
        default;
            break;
    }
    return 0; // zero returned if program is successful
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a loop?

Comment: `<iostream>`, `cin`, and `cout` are specific to C++, and you don't need them anyway.

Comment: Code does *exactly* what you tell it to, line by line. Walk through the logic yourself. You scan a number into `menu_number`. Then you print something out via your switch statement based on the value of `menu_number`. **Then you return from the main function**. Return does not mean start the function over. It means stop executing the function and leave (back to the calling function), setting the return value if there is one.

Comment: It seems fairly clear you're just beginning to learn about programming.  In the book, class notes, or online tutorial, or whatever it is that you're working from, very early on there should be something on looping.  It might help to find that and see why you missed it in the first place, and to compare whatever it says to @dreamlax's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the code here so that it will keep asking you for an entry until you give it one it accepts.

```
int menu_number;
int accepted = 0;

while (!accepted)
{
    if (scanf("%d", &menu_number) != 1)
    {
        puts("Error in input!");
        break; // or "continue;" to keep going
    }

    switch (menu_number)                  //creating the navigation menu
    {
            case 1:
                printf("Flights");
                accepted = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Passengers");
                accepted = 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Reservations");
                accepted = 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: EXTREMELY appreciated! but its given me a problem

Comment: expected ":" before ";" and this error is being highlighted at the default line (at the bottom)

Comment: @user3689367: The line should read `default:` rather than `default;`.

Comment: Also, you should *always* check the result of `scanf`. Reading from a variable with an indeterminate value is undefined behaviour.